# ARM register expected while compiling Android kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, cyanogenmod

I am compiling cyanogenmod 12 for my device Samsung Galaxy Star Pro. When I compile the kernel within the cyanogenmod source, i get the following error:

```
ARM register expected -- `str r2,[ sp,#60 ]'
```

Here is the full output:

http://pastebin.com/ZM0cQpiq

And here is my kernel source:

https://github.com/regalstreak/S7262-Kernel

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I need you to help me fix it. Its an error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! it would be good if you can also mention what have you tried so far fixing it? this is not code out sourcing site where you just post question and someone will fix it for you, for FREE!!  You need to explain what specific problem your facing and what have you tried to fix it which didnt work.  REFER: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oohk...sorry :P I have tried using different sources provided by samsung. but to no avail. I have tried compiling kernel outside the cyanogenmod source and that works. but inside the source with mka bootimage it doesnt work...

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer! Just had to remove the "wide space" from the line.

It was:

```
str r2, [ sp, #S_PC ]   @ bounce exception
```

Changed it to:

```
str r2, [ sp, #S_PC ] @ bounce exception
```

and the problem was fixed :P